# How to split UV edge and then be able to move the resulting UV shells cleanly?

Tags: uv, selection-tools, uv-image-editor

I want to split the selected UV edge in the image below. I know from other questions I am meant to use the 'Y' key (select split) but when I do, I find out that the 'L' key function (select linked) doesn't work, it selects both [new] islands.
[image]

It seems like the 'select linked' function and the 'island' selection mode are not respecting the state of the sticky selection mode.

Does anybody know how I get around this in stock blender or does anybody know an addon that will let me simply split UV edges?

Comment: If Select Linked still selects all the geometry then it's still connected and splitting wasn't done. Try selecting UV faces you want to separate and then execute Split.